# gradle version number in project's build script

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

The standalone [Gradle](https://www.gradle.org/) use 2.1, 2.2.1 etc for versioning, while in Android Studio's project build script, it uses something like :

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.3' //How do I know what is the gradle version 0.13.3 stands for????
    }
```

How can I match gradle version with the mystery number e.g. `0.13.3` and other versions? Where is the reference for it? For example, I would like to use the latest gradle version 2.2.1 in my Android Studio. What is the number to specify in above build script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The standalone Gradle use 2.1, 2.2.1 etc for versioning, while in Android Studio's project build script, it uses something like

`com.android.tools.build:gradle` is not Gradle. It is the Gradle for Android plugin.

> How can I match gradle version with the mystery number e.g. 0.13.3 and other versions?

That depends upon what you mean by this question. Versions of the Gradle for Android plugin have [certain requirements](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility) for a compatible version of Gradle.

> For example, I would like to use the latest gradle version 2.2.1 in my Android Studio. What is the number to specify in above build script?

1.0.0 of the Gradle for Android plugin works with Gradle 2.2.1.